# Image in custom module grid

Tags: module, grid, media-images

I created image attribute and also create image in media custom folder. While form submit i save imgae url in Database it's working fine. I want to show in grid how i show

**my output**

```
http://localhost/Test/media/Custom/Yellow.png
```

Here **Yellow** is attribute name it dynamically change based on user select

Comment: Do you want to show the image in the grid or just the data (http://localhost/Test/media/Custom/Yellow.png) ?

Comment: i want to show image inthis location image available

Comment: in grid i want to show image insted of location

Comment: Just create a custom renderer. Here's a good tutorial on how to do that: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/